# Facebook Requests Dialog: Too many recepients

Tags: facebook, facebook-requests

Hello I'm having problem while sending invitations to my application with the Requests Dialog.

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Too many recipients.

I know that there are limitations on recipients number, but is there any way of increasing this limit?

Answer (score 2):

No,I don't think so, you cant send app request to more than 50 users in one go.